# PostgreSQL HAVING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, having

I posted on here last night looking for help with some homework. I'm down to my last question.

Here's the relevant piece of the schema I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE votesOnPoll(
  user_id int,
  poll_id int,
  option_id int, 
  voteDate date,
  CONSTRAINT votesOnPoll_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id, poll_id),
  CONSTRAINT votesOnPoll_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  CONSTRAINT votesOnPoll_poll_fk FOREIGN KEY (poll_id,option_id) REFERENCES pollOptions(poll_id, option_id)
);
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the `option_id` of poll option with the most votes, as well as the number of votes. This is only on poll 10.

I can successfully return the number of votes for each option with the following query:

```
SELECT p10.oid AS option_id, MAX(p10.votecount)
FROM (SELECT option_id AS oid, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS votecount
      FROM votesOnPoll
      WHERE poll_id = 10
      GROUP BY option_id) AS p10
GROUP BY p10.oid;
```

which, in this case, returns the following relation:

```
option_id | max
----------+-----
        0 |   7
        1 |  10
        2 |  11
```

I would like to trim this down so it only has the tuple `(2, 11)` (or whatever the winning option is).  I thought I would be able to accomplish this by adding the following `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(p10.votecount) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
                                    FROM votesOnPoll
                                    WHERE poll_id = 10
                                    GROUP BY option_id)
```

However, this returns an empty relation instead.

I have confirmed that the inner `SELECT` statement returns what I expect - that is, it returns a relation with a single attribute, which is the number of votes on a particular option.  In this case, that return value is:

```
 count
-------
     7
    10
    11
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaaaand about 5 seconds after posting this, I found the error.  Instead of saying "HAVING COUNT(...)", I used "HAVING MAX(...)", and I am getting the correct information.

Comment: LoL LoL LoL LoL ! You see, I noticed quite some time ago that there's no quicker way to finding the answer to one's own question than to properly formulate the question first.